# Function setTimeout not working after other clicks

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I have created a simple toast, it working in the first time, but when i click it a second time it doesn't work and I have no idea why it doesn't work. I tried to look in other answers but I didn't find
does anyone have any suggestions.

Lets see the code

My toast component

```
export class Toast extends PureComponent<any> {

  state = {
        timePassed: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
       setTimeout( () => {
            this.setTimePassed();
        },2000);
       clearTimeout()
    }

    setTimePassed() {
        this.setState({timePassed: true});
    }

    render() {
        const { color, title, subtitle } = this.props
        if (this.state.timePassed){
            return '';
        }else{
            return (
                <div className="toast">
                    <p>{title}</p>
                    <div>{subtitle}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is the usage

```
export class Product extends PureComponent<any> {

    state = {
        like: true,
        icon: <Icon.HeartEmpt/>,
        toast: ''
    }


    handleClick() {
        this.setState({like: !this.state.like})
        if (this.state.like) {
            this.setState({toast:  <Toast color='green'  title='Produto adicionado' subtitle='Produto adicionado aos favoritos'/>})

        } else {
            this.setState({toast:  <Toast color='red' title='Produto removido' subtitle='Produto removido dos favoritos'/>})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className='product'>
                    {this.state.toast}                  
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or sth of your code? Btw I think it's not a really good idea to store JSX in state, you can store toast object and show flag `show && <Toast ... />` and replace it by `{this.state.toast}` in render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle your Toast disappearance at your `Parent` component rather `Toast` itself. so you trigger setTimeout at your `Product`. Don't store JSX components at store as well like @c0mit said.

I would remove toast's state also. since it depends on `like`, I would store it's content on an object and access through `like` value (which is gonna be `added` or `removed`).

You also need to ensure to clear your setTimeout on your component unmount. and at componentDidUpdate you trigger your setTimeout, but you need check if it setTimeout is not triggered and disPlayToast is `true`.

```
export class Toast extends PureComponent<any> {
 
    render() {
        const { color, title, subtitle } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="toast">
                <p>{title}</p>
                <div>{subtitle}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const toastProps = {
  liked: { 
    color:'green', 
    title:'Produto adicionado',
    subtitle:'Produto adicionado aos favoritos'
  },
  removed: {
    color:'red',
    title: 'Produto removido',
    subtitle:'Produto removido dos favoritos'
    }
  }

class Product extends PureComponent<any, any> {

    state = {
        like: 'removed',
        displayToast: false
    }

    // timeHandler to store setTimeout
    timerHandle = 0

    componentDidUpdate() {
      // to trigger setTimeout validate that Toast is on display
      // and timerHandle 
      if(this.state.displayToast && !this.timerHandle){ 
        this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ displayToast: false });
          // clear timerHandle     
          this.timerHandle = 0;  
        },2000);
      }
    }

      componentWillUnmount = () => {             
    // clearTimeout if it's running               
    if (this.timerHandle) {                  
        clearTimeout(this.timerHandle);      
        this.timerHandle = 0;                
    }                                        
  };                                         


    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(( { like } ) => ({
          like: like === 'liked' ? 'removed' : 'liked', 
          displayToast: true })
        )
    }

    render() {
        const {like, displayToast} = this.state
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>filp</button>
            <div className='product'>
                {displayToast && <Toast {...toastProps[like]} />}                  
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-toast-timeout?file=index.tsx